# Ingress traffic flow in to kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Can anyone please help me understand the ingress traffic flow to a pod in kubernetes? Any web links or documents are much appreciated.

In my application there is a intermittent connection timed out so i want to understand how the traffic is flowing in to cluster and where do i need to enable tcpdump to understand what is happening when there is timeout.

Comment: This question needs more clarity and debugging details.

Comment: I want to understand if someone outside of K8s cluster trying to access my application .... how the traffic will flow... like LB to service to pods ... so i want to understand this flow....

Comment: why dont you check your ingress controller logs?

Comment: i can't find any ingress controller pods in my application namespace... Is it going to be in a different namespace ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain enough information to give you a detailed answer. There are different types of ingress controllers, and load balancers as well.

So, suppose:

- you are using Azure Kubernetes Service
- you are using Azure Load Balancer
- you have two types of backend pods, each has its own dedicated service
- you are using Nginx as ingress controller which is able to do LAYER 7 (OSI) load balancing

Nginx has also its own pods and a service sits in front of these pods. This service has a Service IP which is available only within the AKS cluster. Due to this, additionally you can use Azure Load Balancer (ALB) to make your backend pods available for the public. ALB is a layer 4 load balancer, which sends the incoming traffic to the worker nodes.

Kube-proxy is running on every worker nodes and able to recognize that the traffic from the ALB was destined to the Nginx service.

See the flow on the image below:
[image]

Comment: This kubernetes cluster is deployed on baremetal and I am very new to the K8s. All I know is we are using Loadbalancer service types and using metallb along with it... will appreciate if you can explain the flow on baremetal K8s cluster.